# Use methods added by Fody in same solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, fody

I'm using a custom Fody weaver to add new methods to existing classes. Using dnSpy, I can see that the methods are added but, projects (unit testing and benchmarks) in the same solution with direct dependency, don't compile. If I change these to depend on the NuGet package instead, they compile.
Is there a way to make dependent projects use the Fody generated assembly?

I'm using Fody 5.1.1, FodyHelpers 5.1.1 and Visual Studio 2019 16.3.0 Preview 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no there is not. When using a project reference VS will use the current source to verify the codebase. You cannot tell it to "use the dll". Or at least I have not found a way.